# Can shifting trigger non-attack opportunity actions?

Tags: dnd-4e, shift, opportunity-actions

Part of the Shift rule is this:

> No Opportunity Attacks: Your movement doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks.

However, there are a few Opportunity Actions that do not include attacks.  If such an opportunity action was triggered by movement, could it be set off by a shift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

From the PHB, page 290 (Opportunity Attack): "The most common form of opportunity action is an opportunity attack - a melee basic attack against the creature that provokes it."

And the PHB, page 292 (Shift): "No Opportunity Attacks: If you shift out of a square adjacent to an enemy, you don't provoke an opportunity attack."

This means that Opportunity Attacks are a subset of Opportunity Actions, and the rules for Shifting specifically call out this subset.