# Can Pursuit of the Hunter be triggered in the middle of the enemy's movement?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, immediate-actions, wilden

From [Pursuit of the Hunter](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7443):

> Trigger: An enemy within 2 squares of you moves on its turn

Does the triggering enemy have to *start* its movement within two squares, or can the power be triggered mid-move once the enemy is within range?

Scenario:

- An enemy begins its turn three or more squares away from a Wilden.
- The enemy moves, with part of its path coming within two squares of the Wilden before the movement is complete.

Could the Wilden use Pursuit of the Hunter in the above scenario?

Comment: A nice side-effect I just realized is that, despite the flavour text and being named "pursuit", you could use it to shift out of the target's reach. Good use for squishy and/or ranged-heavy characters ^_^

Comment: @EricBurigo - You're right.  We've already got that covered in another discussion.  http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6025/197

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, movement can be reacted to on a square by square basis.

From the Immediate Action definition <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=120)</sup>:

> If a creature triggers your immediate reaction while moving (by coming into range, for example), you take your action before the creature finishes moving but after it has moved at least 1 square